Designing a LKM userspace interface: ioctl vs. netlink IPC for high data volume communication
Problem definition:
I need to read the memory of a foreign process. Not every linux system permits access to procfs. Some anti-debugging/anti-tampering measures also use inotify to watch accesses to /proc/pid/{maps,mem} files.
My solution is to write a kernel module that will provide a bespoke interface to both the memory and the memory maps of foreign processes.

Requirements & constraints:
I am new to kernel development and would like some guidance on the design of the interface for this module before I commit to an approach.

1) The interface needs to reliably return large amounts of data.
Large processes have thousands of segments. Each segment contains a 'backing file path' field that can be up to PATH_MAX (4096) characters long. I am interested in this field and would like my module to return it for each segment (In addition to all other fields ofcourse).
For simplicity, let's imagine a structure representing a single segment in a memory map is 4Kb (PATH_MAX + other fields). A map representing a process with 5000 segments will require 20Mb of space. This means my interface needs to be able to return several megabytes worth of structures.
Whichever interface I choose will also need to support writing to process memory, although I am content to limit that to 4Kb per call.

2) The interface should be thread-safe or lockable.
This module is a part of a library, which itself is used by numerous projects. I expect multiple processes will need to use this module at the same time. At the bare minimum I need to be able to place a lock on the interface while one process uses it.

Ideas so far:
From my research it appears that ioctl is the standard approach. I have also come across netlink IPC sockets. While they are more complicated, they seem to be better suited for communication of high volume data. I am not sure if they are necessary, or if the added complexity is worth it in this case.

Summary of questions:

Given the requirements, which interface should I opt for? ioctl or netlink IPC sockets?

How do I ensure that my chosen interface is able to return large buffers of structures to userspace, and be thread-safe?



use /proc/pid/{maps,mem}

I am explicitly avoiding procfs because inotify can be used by userspace processes to watch accesses to their own memory via procfs.

maybe patch the kernel so they can't, because that IS the way to access another process's memory. You could also ptrace them and force them to unwatch it. That would be a hack.

I'd like to distribute this LKM as part of a library. I may be able to hide procfs accesses with kprobes, but I am taking this opportunity to learn proper kernel programming by implementing an entirely new interface. I'm about to commit to an ioctl design as it seems most appropriate.
